ActivityReportExtension: DeviceActivityReportScene empty when CoreData is used
I created a DeviceActivityReportScene and need to call CoreData to fetch some data I need for the reports. I am sharing CoreData with the ActivityReportExtension via AppGroups. When I create a regular report without calling the database, everything works fine.
But when I call something like this
 func makeConfiguration(representing data: DeviceActivityResults<DeviceActivityData>) async -> [ActivityData] {
    let result = await repository.fetchData()
    ...

nothing is shown on the screen.
The prints are also a bit strange:
Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.

LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database"

In some articles I read that reading databases should work and only saving data from the extension is not allowed.
